# what should ip be for socket programming?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ip

I have made a ChatApplication by C#.It works with localnetwork ip(127.0.0.1) very well . But I wanna it works in different machines with different modems and ips.What should Ip be for the socket?

Comment: For listening, it should be INADDR_ANY, `0.0.0.0.` or the IPv6 equivalent.

Comment: what about port? is it 9000 good?

Comment: Any free port you like, but you didn't ask about ports, you asked about IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server component in you chat applications should be listening at `INADDR_ANY` or `0.0.0.0`
The Chat client should connect to the ip address of the server machine.